# How can I turn an existing Windows Server 2008 EBS-backed instance into a S3-backed (instance-backed) AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs

I understand there is no direct conversion to get from EBS to S3. But is there some series of steps that can make this happen, or is rebuilding the image from scratch the best option?

Is there a way to create a volume or snapshot, download it, reupload it to S3, and then bundle it as an S3 AMI?

Thanks for any help

Comment: The typical approach is to use `ec2-bundle-vol` and `ec2-upload-bundle` - both run from the running instance. (I don't use Windows servers, but it should still work). Once your bundle is uploaded to S3, you can use the AWS console or `ec2-register` to register the AMI and be able to launch it.

Comment: I looked into this. Unfortunately, ec2-bundle-vol and ec2-upload-bundle only come as bash files, not windows cmd files.

Comment: Looks like the windows equivalent is ec2-bundle-instance. Perhaps the procedure described in [the docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-s3.html) will work.

Comment: I gave this a shot but it wouldn't work. Additionally, on the console website, the bundle instance command is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create an instance-store (S3 based) AMI for Windows 2008 on Amazon EC2.

There is a limit of 10GB for the boot disk on an instance-store AMI and Windows 2008 requires more.

I list this as reason #11 for why [you should use EBS boot instances on Amazon EC2](http://alestic.com/2012/01/ec2-ebs-boot-recommended).

*Disclaimer: I am the furthest thing from a Windows expert there is, but I've been around AWS/EC2 long enough to have learned this particular Windows 2008 limitation from Amazon and others.*